# External legend in Highcharts

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, highcharts

I want to create my own legend instead of using the Highcharts one.

The idea is to show the series data in an external table and by clicking in one row, show or hide the series in the chart.

Is this somehow possible with Highcharts? I couldn't find any way to relate an external element with a specific series.

---

**Update**

To illustrate it a bit better imagine that I want to create a legend like the one I did in this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/msSr7/

Which is mainly like so:

```
<div class="myLegend">My legend for serie 1 </div>
<div class="myLegend">My legend for serie 1 </div>
```

Comment: To answer I say : Yes it is possible!

Comment: @Bellash could you elaborate it? In which way should I link the element with the series?

Comment: You are the one who define the legends in this fidle: http://jsfiddle.net/tresorunikin/pk57b/ is this what you want to do?

Comment: @Bellash you are defining them in the initialization... that's not what I asked for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is to click on our custom legend item to toggle the series visibility you can try this:

```
<div class="myLegend" id="0">My legend for serie 1</div>
<div class="myLegend" id="1">My legend for serie 2</div>
```

I have given each div an ID equal to the series number. Then in javascript do:

```
$('div.myLegend').click(function () {
    var theSeries = $(this).attr('id');
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    var series = chart.series[theSeries];

    if (series.visible) {
        series.hide();
    } else {
        series.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: And how are you suppose to know the ID of each series when they are dynamically generated? How can you extract the ID of each one?

Comment: If you do not define the index of the series HC will generate them as zero-based. The first series you add is 0, the second one you add is 1, etc. You can also explicitly set the id of a series upon creation and use that as the "key" to find which series to toggle visibility. Or you can assign your own attribute and value that you check. Take a look at http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.id. In my example code I am using the series index value as the div.id attribute value.

Comment: I'm using highstocks but I managed to do what you are talking about by using the chart.get() method, otherwise it won't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-hide/

#### html

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<button id="button">Select first series</button>
```

#### javascript

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                showCheckbox: true
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }, {
            data: [129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4]
        }]

    });


    // the button action
    $('#button').click(function() {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        chart.series[0].select();
    });
});
```

So in your table row,you can call the .select depending on the series

Comment: Again, no. The legend is being defined in the initialization. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/6s3YX/. I want to hide or show the series when clicking in "My legend for serie X"

Comment: There's some assumption that you're naming the series based on the legend... I reworked it a little to better illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/6s3YX/2/